# What is to correct syntax for adding a shard to an mongo db that requires authentication

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to add a shard to mongos using the sh.addShard command following this documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/
the example given is:

```
sh.addShard( "rs1/mongodb0.example.net:27018" )
```

However the db that I am trying to connect to requires authentication.

```
sh.addShard( "rs0/admin:XXXXXpasswordXXXXXXXX@XXX.XX.XX.XXX:27018" )
```

returns this the message:

> "More than one ':' detected. If this is an ipv6 address, it needs to
>   be surrounded by '[' and ']'

Running the command without the auth returns:

> "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true }"

How can I add auth credentials to the host whilst maintaining the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addShard() will not take any authentication credentials from the best of my knowledge.

Make sure you are under the admin db `use admin` and make sure if auth is turned on you successfully authenticate `db.auth("username", "password")`

If your cluster has keyFile authentication on, you will need top copy the keyFile to each host and make sure the user running mongod has access to it (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/)